# How to call multiple function calls at once

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to call a function from all of class instances at once?

```js
function updateEverything() {
  // call update function of all of the Example instances
}

class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.data = { /* ... */ }
  }

  update() {
    // do something with this.data
  }
}
```

I tried to come up with a way of using callbacks but that flew over my head and I didn't find any other solution.

Comment: You could spawn off `setTimeout`s with a threshold of 0, but technically they will not all run at a single time, since javascript in the browser is primarily single threaded.  They will all time share the process.

Comment: So, the bigger question.  What's the problem?  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: in that case store the instances in an array , call any functions on oall of the items in the array.

Comment: My classes are returning a value and the data within them may be altered but the changes would be viewed after Example.update would have been called.
There can be multiple classes that are active and displaying data so I'd like to call the update of all of them at once.

I tried to make the question a bit broader so that it could be used to find a solution for other peoples problems instead of only solving mine.

Comment: It's a decorate pattern usecase you have , in that case in vanillaJS you have one option that is inherit tje class from a class in whose custructore you store the instance refrence in an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the variables in a array, the you just need:

```
array.forEach(el => el.update())
```

Otherwise you can use a sort of static property to store all the variables that you have instantiated:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    if(!Example.instances)
      Example.instances = [];
    Example.instances.push(this);
    this.data = {a: 1}
  }

  update() {
    console.log('update is called');
  }
  static updateAll(){
    if(Example.instances)
      Example.instances.forEach(el => el.update());
  }
}
const arr = [
  new Example(), // <-- doesn't need to be in a array
  new Example(), // <-- doesn't need to be in a array
  new Example(), // <-- doesn't need to be in a array
]
Example.updateAll();
```